# How to remove empty indentation/spaces from empty lines in VS code or via a task runner

Tags: visual-studio-code, ide

I use Visual Studio Code, I have been manually removing the spaces/tabs from blank lines (keeping the blank line but starting at col 1). I want to keep a blank line, but it be a completely empty line.

Is there a way to do this automatically, whether that be a VS Code extension, some form of task runner, etc?

It's annoying when editing code that occasionally some lines have lines with rouge indents/spaces, that then get committed to git.

Comment: key combo `Ctrl+K Ctrl+X`

Comment: why not just turn on whitespace trimming? there's a setting for that.